# pass arguments in dockerfile?

Tags: bash, docker

I want to pass an argument to my dockerfile such that I should be able to use that argument in my run command but it seems I am not able to do so

I am using a simple bash file that will trigger the docker build and docker run

```
FROM openjdk:8 AS SCRATCH

WORKDIR /

ADD . .

RUN apt install unzip

RUN unzip target/universal/rule_engine-1.0.zip -d target/universal/rule_engine-1.0

COPY target/universal/rule_engine-1.0 .

ENV MONGO_DB_HOST="host.docker.internal"
ENV MONGO_DB_PORT="27017"

EXPOSE 9000

ARG path

CMD target/universal/rule_engine-1.0/bin/rule_engine -Dconfig.file=$path
```

above is my dockerfile
and below is my bash file which will access this dockerfile

```
#!/bin/bash

# change the current path to rule engine path
cd /Users/zomato/Documents/Intern_Project/rule_engine

sbt dist

ENVIR=$1

config=""
if [ $ENVIR == "local" ]
then
    config=conf/application.conf
elif [ $ENVIR == "staging" ]
then
    config=conf/staging.conf
else
    config=conf/production.conf
fi

echo $config
docker build --build-arg path=$config -t rule_engine_zip .
docker run -i -t -p 9000:9000 rule_engine_zip
```

but when i access the dockerfile through bash script which will set config variable I am not able to set path variable in last line of dockerfile to the value of config.

Comment: Anything you pass in an `ARG` is compiled into the image – think of `docker build` as similar to `sbt dist` in your setup.  If you can update your application to look for the file location in an environment variable rather than a Java property, then you can pass the location using the `docker run -e` option, without rebuilding the image.

Comment: Hi @William Martens 
i don't think this is the problem I am facing which you mentioned in your comment. thanks btw

Comment: Hi @David Maze 
thanks for sharing your Knowledge. I will try this

Comment: @Lazy_Nerd Oh right,  thanks for telling!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ARG` values won't be available after the image is built, so
a running container won’t have access to those values. To dynamically set an env variable, you can combine both `ARG` and `ENV` (since `ENV` can't be overridden):

```
ARG PATH
ENV P=${PATH}
CMD target/universal/rule_engine-1.0/bin/rule_engine -Dconfig.file=$P
```

For further explanation, I recommend this [article](https://vsupalov.com/docker-arg-vs-env/), which explains the difference between `ARG` and `ENV` in a clear way:

[image]

As you can see from the above image, the `ARG` values are available only during the image build.